# digitalClock1 control in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

i have downloaded "Wconrtol" components and it contains two items
the first is clockcontrol and the second is CircularGauge 
i included the components correctly but i cant set the value of the clock in the proporeties

```
these lines dosents works :
digitalClock1.Value = datetime.now.tostring();
digitalClock1.Value =datetime.today();
```

please help..what is the correct thing to set value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide `TimeSpan` as follows:

```
digitalClock1.Value = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```